# How does Time Machine deal with moved files

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

I have a large photo library (a couple of 100GBs of data) on an external hard drive, but I will need to move it to a different drive.

When moving the files, will time machine try to backup up all the moved files again, so my photo library will be stored twice in the backup set - or is it able to recognize that the "new" files are indeed identical to existing files in its history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time Machine works at the file level.  Change a single byte in a file, and it backs up again.  Move it into a new directory, technically it's a new file, so new backup.  There is no way to avoid this in the current implementation.  Ideally future enhancements to Time Machine will enable block level backups and some form of de-duplication, which will fix both the above scenarios, but for now you just have to be aware of it.  What you can choose to do, if you like, is confirm that the new location is successfully backed u p in the new place, and then manually remove the old location from your Time Machine.  This clearly doesn't prevent the need from repeating the backup, but it does at least stop you doubling the storage requirements.  Having said that, the old stuff will naturally get recycled off as it's no longer required should the backup drive fill.

Comment: This is especially painful for mutable disk images and virtual machines. In those cases, I suggest using sparebundles, which are composed out of a large number of small files. A small change results in a small number of changes in a few small files, rather than requiring a backup of an entire disk image for a single small change.

Answer (score 1):

In short: TimeCapsule will backup everything again. That's the reason why I backup big data manually.